# Cron job unsuccessful

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am very new to Cron scheduling and Linux in general. I have created a Python code (Test_Analysis.py) that analyzes some data and generates an excel sheet which holds the results of the analysis. I then email this excel sheet to myself. My goal is to create an automated schedule for this process (analysis and report email) that runs at a specific time every day, say 5.00 am.

I tried the Cron scheduling for this. The email is not getting sent using Cron Scheduling. The funny part is that just to learn how Cron works, I created a simple test script (Test_Cron.py) that also sends me an email. For this script, I do get automated emails as I have scheduled them. I just don't get them for my original script (Test_Analysis.py).

Here are my cron schedules for both the scripts (both scripts are in the same folder)

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Cron.py &> /tmp/Test_Cron.log

*/15 * * * * python /home/abc/anuj/TPA/Test_Analysis.py &> /tmp/Test_Analysis.log
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

PS : I am logging into a remote linux server using SSH for doing this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: there should be some difference in scripts, or..?

Answer (score 0):

In your actual Python script (say, test.py), there has to be at least print() function, outputting something into standard output, 
say:

```
def send_email():
    """whatever email logic you implement"""
    pass

def process_cron():
    try:
        send_email()
        print("Successfully sent email")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending email {}".format(e))


process_cron()
```

Then, the call to

```
python test.py >> test_cron.log
```

will write the result (or the error) of the script into the log, so you'll see what exactly happens in the test_cron.log file. if set as cron tab, it will log periodically and you'll see what's going on.